# Taskbar button "Bins"

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell, taskbar

I stumbled across something very interesting http://www.1upindustries.com/Bins/Default.aspx.

Is it an application that is pinned to the bar and renders it's icon based on its contents, then also renders a hover menu with thumbnail to simulate the windows taskbar? What about the handles above the buttons? how do they prevent the running program from displaying in the taskbar with a separate icon?

For the life of me I cant figure out how they accomplish it without replacing the taskbar, Any Ideas?

Comment: They are hacking into taskbar internals and are making the Windows application compatibility team curse their name. Notice that they had to issue an update for Windows 8.

Comment: That's really what interests me the most!